# Show that $f(x, y, z) = (x + y + z, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 , x^3 + y^3 + z^3)$ is a local diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Show that $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $$f(x, y, z) = (x + y + z, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 , x^3 + y^3 + z^3)$$ is a local diffeormorphism. I'm also supposed to find the domain.

So, if I want to use the Inverse Function Theorem, I need to calculate the points where $\det(f'(x,y,z)) \ne 0$, which is just calculus:

$$\det(f'(x,y,z))=6(xy^2-x^2y+x^2z-xz^2+yz^2-zy^2) . $$

The point $0$ is obvious. How can I find the others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** We can factor $$(\det f')(x, y, z) = 6 (y - z) (z - x) (x - y) .$$

Comment: Ah, great. Is it a known function? Is there any technique to factor it that easily?

Comment: Well, the square of this expression is, up to an overall constant, the discriminant of the function $g(t) = (t - x) (t - y) (t - z)$, and so it measures whether any two of the quantities $x, y, z$ coincide. As for factoring, one can play around with groupings. Alternatively, the symmetry of $f$ implies when we permute $(x, y, z)$ that $\det (f')$ can only change by sign. Since $\det (f')$ is homogeneous of degree $3$, and factorization must have a linear factor, and there simply aren't very many expressions of the right degree with a linear factor.